Does the Hamiltonian of a free scalar field represent energy?
I know that in classical physics the Hamiltonian of a system does not represent the energy of the system if the Lagrangian is time-dependent.
Since the Lagrangian for a free scalar field $\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu \phi)$ technically depends on time, since it implicitly depends on $x^0$, does that mean that the Hamiltonian does not represent energy in this case?
Edit: because I am getting some hate from people who apparently do not even know what $\phi(x)$ is, please note that $\phi(x)$ has an $e^{\pm i E t}$ term. So the Lagrangian does depend on $t$ even if not explicitly.

Think about $L(x,\dot x)$ for a point particle, such a harmonic oscillator. Is that time-dependent just because it is velocity-dependent? Your question really has nothing to do with field theory.

I didn’t say anything about velocity dependence. The Lagrangian does depend on time because it has a $e^{iEt}$ factor.  Your answer really has nothing to do with field theory.

This community is becoming so hostile! Why am I getting 5 downvotes for asking a question about something that I do not understand? Isn't this the whole purpose? Plus it isn’t like it’s an obvious question, the proof is no one gave a correct answer.

The answer lies in the reason why "the Hamiltonian does not represent energy if the Lagrangian is time-dependent" to begin with. The reason for this comes from the fact that
$$\frac{dH}{dt} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial t} = 0.$$
So if the Lagrangian does not depend explicitly on time, then the Hamiltonian is still conserved and can be thought of as energy. So all arguments that state that the Lagrangian of a free scalar field does not depend on time are wrong, it does depend on time via the $e^{\pm iEt}$ facctors, it just doesn't depend explicitly on time.

Could the smartass who gave a downvote explain why they do not like this answer?


Since the Lagrangian for a free scalar field $\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu \phi)$ technically depends on time

Despite the horrible notation, you should not consider this to expression to depend on time (yet). Time dependence is only included implicitly if you literally have substituted in the classical fields $\phi(x,t)$ and $\partial_\mu\phi(x,t)$. But, despite the confusing notation, you are not supposed to do this until you are generating the classical equations of motion.
In other words, your $\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu \phi)$ is better understood as a function of five independent variables and can be written as $\mathcal{L}(a,b_\mu)$.
So, for example, in an action, you can use an arbitrary function $f(x,t)$ like:
$$
S[f] = \int \mathcal{L}(f(x,t),\partial_\mu f(x,t))\;,
$$
and vary this action ($f(x,t)\to f(x,t)+\epsilon g(x,t)$) to arrive at the equations of motion:
$$
\partial_\mu \left.\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial b_\mu }\right|_{a=\phi_{cl}(x,t), b_\mu=\partial_\mu\phi_cl(x,t)}-\left.\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial a}\right|_{a=\phi_{cl}(x,t), b_\mu=\partial_\mu\phi_cl(x,t)}=0
$$

does that mean that the Hamiltonian does not represent energy in this case?

No.

Further Explanation:
A Lagrangian function like
$$
L(x,v) = mv^2/2 - kx^2/2
$$
does not depend on time. The variables $x$ and $v$ are just two symbols that denote two independent variables. If the fact that $v$ is the same letter that the word "velocity" starts with is confusing, then use different letters like:
$$
L(a,b) = mb^2/2 - ka^2/2\;.
$$
It is only when you plug in $a=x(t)$ and $b=\dot x(t)$ for a specific path that time comes into the picture. You plug in $a=x(t)$ and $b=\dot x(t)$ as part of your prescription for generating the classical equations of motion a la:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial b}\right|_{a=x(t), b=\dot x(t)}-\left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}\right|_{a=x(t), b=\dot x(t)}=0
$$
Similarly, a Lagrangian function like
$$
L(\phi, \partial \phi) = m(\partial \phi)^2/2 - k(\phi)^2/2
$$
does not depend on time, although the notation is far more horrible here.
The variables $\phi$ and $\partial \phi$ should be thought of as just two symbols that denote two independent variables. It is less confusing to use different letters like:
$$
L(a,b) = mb^2/2 - ka^2/2\;.
$$
It is only when you plug in $a=\phi(x,t)$ and $b=\partial \phi(x,t)$ for a specific path that time comes into the picture. You plug in $a=\phi(x,t)$ and $b=\partial \phi(x,t)$ as part of your prescription for generating the classical equations of motion a la:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial b_\mu}\right|_{a=\phi(x,t), b=\partial \phi(x, t)}-\left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}\right|_{a=\phi(x,t), b=\partial \phi(x,t)}=0
$$

OH right, even classically $x$ is $x(t)$. This makes sense, thank you.
